# プログラムを書き換えたい

Tags: c

以下に示すプログラムは、100回のスループット率、実加工数、仕掛け品数を出力するものです。

つまり、やりたいことは下記の出力結果の「Through put ratio」を全て足して、それを100で割るということですが、どのようにプログラムをすれば期待している出力になるのでしょうか。
お願いします。

**ソースコード:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

//機械の構造体の用意
struct machine_type{
  int temochi,kano_kako_su,jitsu_kako_su,kimatsu_zaiko;
};
/* ============================================ */
/*   グローバル変数宣言部                       */
/* ============================================ */
struct machine_type mA,mB,mC;
int i,M,Run;
int total_jitsu_kako_su,total_shikake;
int j;

void machine_A(void);
void machine_B(void);
void machine_C(void);
void ABC(void);

void main()
{
    //乱数の初期化
    srand((unsigned) time(NULL));
    Run=100;
    for(j=0;j<Run;j++){
        printf("%d\t",j);
        ABC();
    }
}

/* 50期分のシミュレーション */
void ABC(void)
{
    //機械の在庫の初期化
    mA.kimatsu_zaiko=0;
    mB.kimatsu_zaiko=0;
    mC.kimatsu_zaiko=0;

    //集計用の変数初期化
    total_jitsu_kako_su=0;
    total_shikake=0;

    //50期の計算
    for(i=1;i<=50;i++){
        machine_A();        
        if(i>=2){
            machine_B();
        }
        if(i>=3){
            machine_C();
        }
    }
    //期末在庫と仕掛品数の集計
    //実加工数合計と仕掛品数を画面に表示する．
    //スループットを計算して画面に表示する．
    total_shikake=mA.kimatsu_zaiko+mB.kimatsu_zaiko+mC.kimatsu_zaiko;
    printf("Total_jitsu_kako_su =%d\n Total_shikake =%d\n Through put ratio =%lf\n",total_jitsu_kako_su,total_shikake,(double)total_jitsu_kako_su/150);
}

/* machine_A */
void machine_A(){
    double r;

    mA.temochi=mA.kimatsu_zaiko+3;

    r=rand()/(double)RAND_MAX;//[0,1)乱数
    if(r<0.2){
        mA.kano_kako_su=0;
    }
    if(0.2<=r&&r<0.4){
        mA.kano_kako_su=1;
    }
    if(0.4<=r){
        mA.kano_kako_su=5;
    }

    if(mA.temochi<=mA.kano_kako_su){
        mA.jitsu_kako_su=mA.temochi;
    }else{
        mA.jitsu_kako_su=mA.kano_kako_su;
    }
    mA.kimatsu_zaiko=mA.temochi-mA.jitsu_kako_su;
}
/* machine_B */
void machine_B(){
    double r;

    mB.temochi=mB.kimatsu_zaiko+mA.jitsu_kako_su;

    r=rand()/(double)RAND_MAX;//[0,1)乱数
    if(r<0.2){
        mB.kano_kako_su=0;
    }
    if(0.2<=r&&r<0.4){
        mB.kano_kako_su=1;
    }
    if(0.4<=r){
        mB.kano_kako_su=5;
    }

    if(mB.temochi<=mB.kano_kako_su){
        mB.jitsu_kako_su=mB.temochi;
    }else{
        mB.jitsu_kako_su=mB.kano_kako_su;
    }
    mB.kimatsu_zaiko=mB.temochi-mB.jitsu_kako_su;
}
/* machine_C */
void machine_C(){
    double r;

    mC.temochi=mC.kimatsu_zaiko+mB.jitsu_kako_su;

    r=rand()/(double)RAND_MAX;//[0,1)乱数
    if(r<0.2){
        mC.kano_kako_su=0;
    }
    if(0.2<=r&&r<0.4){
        mC.kano_kako_su=1;
    }
    if(0.4<=r){
        mC.kano_kako_su=5;
    }

    if(mC.temochi<=mC.kano_kako_su){
        mC.jitsu_kako_su=mC.temochi;
    }else{
        mC.jitsu_kako_su=mC.kano_kako_su;
    }
    mC.kimatsu_zaiko=mC.temochi-mC.jitsu_kako_su;
    //実加工数合計の集計
    total_jitsu_kako_su=total_jitsu_kako_su+mC.jitsu_kako_su;
}
```

**実行結果:**

```
$ ./a.out
0   Total_jitsu_kako_su =97
 Total_shikake =47
 Through put ratio =0.646667
1   Total_jitsu_kako_su =120
 Total_shikake =27
 Through put ratio =0.800000
2   Total_jitsu_kako_su =117
 Total_shikake =28
 Through put ratio =0.780000
3   Total_jitsu_kako_su =124
 Total_shikake =25
 Through put ratio =0.826667
4   Total_jitsu_kako_su =114
 Total_shikake =30
 Through put ratio =0.760000
5   Total_jitsu_kako_su =135
 Total_shikake =9
 Through put ratio =0.900000
6   Total_jitsu_kako_su =131
 Total_shikake =13
 Through put ratio =0.873333
7   Total_jitsu_kako_su =112
 Total_shikake =35
 Through put ratio =0.746667
8   Total_jitsu_kako_su =122
 Total_shikake =22
 Through put ratio =0.813333
9   Total_jitsu_kako_su =126
 Total_shikake =20
 Through put ratio =0.840000
10  Total_jitsu_kako_su =120
 Total_shikake =30
 Through put ratio =0.800000
11  Total_jitsu_kako_su =135
 Total_shikake =12
 Through put ratio =0.900000
12  Total_jitsu_kako_su =126
 Total_shikake =18
 Through put ratio =0.840000
13  Total_jitsu_kako_su =126
 Total_shikake =18
 Through put ratio =0.840000
14  Total_jitsu_kako_su =125
 Total_shikake =23
 Through put ratio =0.833333
15  Total_jitsu_kako_su =134
 Total_shikake =10
 Through put ratio =0.893333
16  Total_jitsu_kako_su =127
 Total_shikake =22
 Through put ratio =0.846667
17  Total_jitsu_kako_su =114
 Total_shikake =30
 Through put ratio =0.760000
18  Total_jitsu_kako_su =126
 Total_shikake =19
 Through put ratio =0.840000
19  Total_jitsu_kako_su =120
 Total_shikake =24
 Through put ratio =0.800000
20  Total_jitsu_kako_su =132
 Total_shikake =12
 Through put ratio =0.880000
21  Total_jitsu_kako_su =138
 Total_shikake =6
 Through put ratio =0.920000
22  Total_jitsu_kako_su =119
 Total_shikake =28
 Through put ratio =0.793333
23  Total_jitsu_kako_su =108
 Total_shikake =38
 Through put ratio =0.720000
24  Total_jitsu_kako_su =120
 Total_shikake =27
 Through put ratio =0.800000
25  Total_jitsu_kako_su =139
 Total_shikake =9
 Through put ratio =0.926667
26  Total_jitsu_kako_su =138
 Total_shikake =11
 Through put ratio =0.920000
27  Total_jitsu_kako_su =137
 Total_shikake =9
 Through put ratio =0.913333
28  Total_jitsu_kako_su =108
 Total_shikake =38
 Through put ratio =0.720000
29  Total_jitsu_kako_su =128
 Total_shikake =20
 Through put ratio =0.853333
30  Total_jitsu_kako_su =95
 Total_shikake =52
 Through put ratio =0.633333
31  Total_jitsu_kako_su =125
 Total_shikake =24
 Through put ratio =0.833333
32  Total_jitsu_kako_su =130
 Total_shikake =17
 Through put ratio =0.866667
33  Total_jitsu_kako_su =139
 Total_shikake =11
 Through put ratio =0.926667
34  Total_jitsu_kako_su =131
 Total_shikake =16
 Through put ratio =0.873333
35  Total_jitsu_kako_su =127
 Total_shikake =17
 Through put ratio =0.846667
36  Total_jitsu_kako_su =127
 Total_shikake =21
 Through put ratio =0.846667
37  Total_jitsu_kako_su =119
 Total_shikake =27
 Through put ratio =0.793333
38  Total_jitsu_kako_su =123
 Total_shikake =22
 Through put ratio =0.820000
39  Total_jitsu_kako_su =122
 Total_shikake =25
 Through put ratio =0.813333
40  Total_jitsu_kako_su =99
 Total_shikake =45
 Through put ratio =0.660000
41  Total_jitsu_kako_su =119
 Total_shikake =25
 Through put ratio =0.793333
42  Total_jitsu_kako_su =124
 Total_shikake =25
 Through put ratio =0.826667
43  Total_jitsu_kako_su =100
 Total_shikake =46
 Through put ratio =0.666667
44  Total_jitsu_kako_su =125
 Total_shikake =21
 Through put ratio =0.833333
45  Total_jitsu_kako_su =116
 Total_shikake =33
 Through put ratio =0.773333
46  Total_jitsu_kako_su =127
 Total_shikake =17
 Through put ratio =0.846667
47  Total_jitsu_kako_su =128
 Total_shikake =18
 Through put ratio =0.853333
48  Total_jitsu_kako_su =128
 Total_shikake =19
 Through put ratio =0.853333
49  Total_jitsu_kako_su =128
 Total_shikake =21
 Through put ratio =0.853333
50  Total_jitsu_kako_su =128
 Total_shikake =17
 Through put ratio =0.853333
51  Total_jitsu_kako_su =129
 Total_shikake =21
 Through put ratio =0.860000
52  Total_jitsu_kako_su =119
 Total_shikake =27
 Through put ratio =0.793333
53  Total_jitsu_kako_su =114
 Total_shikake =33
 Through put ratio =0.760000
54  Total_jitsu_kako_su =126
 Total_shikake =20
 Through put ratio =0.840000
55  Total_jitsu_kako_su =125
 Total_shikake =19
 Through put ratio =0.833333
56  Total_jitsu_kako_su =109
 Total_shikake =36
 Through put ratio =0.726667
57  Total_jitsu_kako_su =130
 Total_shikake =16
 Through put ratio =0.866667
58  Total_jitsu_kako_su =132
 Total_shikake =18
 Through put ratio =0.880000
59  Total_jitsu_kako_su =137
 Total_shikake =10
 Through put ratio =0.913333
60  Total_jitsu_kako_su =122
 Total_shikake =25
 Through put ratio =0.813333
61  Total_jitsu_kako_su =124
 Total_shikake =23
 Through put ratio =0.826667
62  Total_jitsu_kako_su =118
 Total_shikake =28
 Through put ratio =0.786667
63  Total_jitsu_kako_su =130
 Total_shikake =17
 Through put ratio =0.866667
64  Total_jitsu_kako_su =130
 Total_shikake =17
 Through put ratio =0.866667
65  Total_jitsu_kako_su =127
 Total_shikake =22
 Through put ratio =0.846667
66  Total_jitsu_kako_su =115
 Total_shikake =35
 Through put ratio =0.766667
67  Total_jitsu_kako_su =117
 Total_shikake =28
 Through put ratio =0.780000
68  Total_jitsu_kako_su =119
 Total_shikake =28
 Through put ratio =0.793333
69  Total_jitsu_kako_su =123
 Total_shikake =24
 Through put ratio =0.820000
70  Total_jitsu_kako_su =137
 Total_shikake =10
 Through put ratio =0.913333
71  Total_jitsu_kako_su =107
 Total_shikake =43
 Through put ratio =0.713333
72  Total_jitsu_kako_su =131
 Total_shikake =19
 Through put ratio =0.873333
73  Total_jitsu_kako_su =135
 Total_shikake =9
 Through put ratio =0.900000
74  Total_jitsu_kako_su =134
 Total_shikake =12
 Through put ratio =0.893333
75  Total_jitsu_kako_su =119
 Total_shikake =31
 Through put ratio =0.793333
76  Total_jitsu_kako_su =126
 Total_shikake =18
 Through put ratio =0.840000
77  Total_jitsu_kako_su =131
 Total_shikake =14
 Through put ratio =0.873333
78  Total_jitsu_kako_su =117
 Total_shikake =27
 Through put ratio =0.780000
79  Total_jitsu_kako_su =118
 Total_shikake =28
 Through put ratio =0.786667
80  Total_jitsu_kako_su =114
 Total_shikake =32
 Through put ratio =0.760000
81  Total_jitsu_kako_su =108
 Total_shikake =36
 Through put ratio =0.720000
82  Total_jitsu_kako_su =125
 Total_shikake =19
 Through put ratio =0.833333
83  Total_jitsu_kako_su =122
 Total_shikake =22
 Through put ratio =0.813333
84  Total_jitsu_kako_su =132
 Total_shikake =14
 Through put ratio =0.880000
85  Total_jitsu_kako_su =106
 Total_shikake =38
 Through put ratio =0.706667
86  Total_jitsu_kako_su =137
 Total_shikake =10
 Through put ratio =0.913333
87  Total_jitsu_kako_su =122
 Total_shikake =27
 Through put ratio =0.813333
88  Total_jitsu_kako_su =129
 Total_shikake =21
 Through put ratio =0.860000
89  Total_jitsu_kako_su =132
 Total_shikake =15
 Through put ratio =0.880000
90  Total_jitsu_kako_su =114
 Total_shikake =35
 Through put ratio =0.760000
91  Total_jitsu_kako_su =138
 Total_shikake =12
 Through put ratio =0.920000
92  Total_jitsu_kako_su =109
 Total_shikake =40
 Through put ratio =0.726667
93  Total_jitsu_kako_su =127
 Total_shikake =20
 Through put ratio =0.846667
94  Total_jitsu_kako_su =125
 Total_shikake =19
 Through put ratio =0.833333
95  Total_jitsu_kako_su =98
 Total_shikake =47
 Through put ratio =0.653333
96  Total_jitsu_kako_su =119
 Total_shikake =28
 Through put ratio =0.793333
97  Total_jitsu_kako_su =123
 Total_shikake =21
 Through put ratio =0.820000
98  Total_jitsu_kako_su =114
 Total_shikake =33
 Through put ratio =0.760000
99  Total_jitsu_kako_su =127
 Total_shikake =20
 Through put ratio =0.846667
```

Comment: タイトルには質問の概要を書いてください。

Comment: プログラムを組むためには、「プログラム的思考でアルゴリズムを考えること」と、「言語仕様に沿ってアルゴリズムを再現する」の二つが必要になります。今回の場合はどっちが「わからない」といっていますか？

Comment: 以前の質問と類似で、何か出された課題であって元のプログラム自身をあまり理解していないとか？ 回答に付いたコメントからすると、それらを理解していないために丸投げ状態のような感じです。

Answer (score 1):

変数を一つ用意し、そこに、出力結果の「Through put ratio」を全て足して行き、最後に100で割りましょう。
それでお望みのことができます

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。その「出力結果をすべてたしていく」プログラムがよくわからないのですが、教えていただけると助かります